# In Dafny, how can I fix the "value does not satisfy the subset constraints of 'nat'" error on division?

Tags: integer-division, formal-verification, dafny

[This Dafny code](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/dtb6X):

```
method Div(n: nat, d: nat) returns (q: nat)
  requires d > 1
{
  q := n / (d - 1);
}
```

produces this error:

```
Dafny 2.1.1.10209
stdin.dfy(4,9): Error: value does not satisfy the subset constraints of 'nat'

Dafny program verifier finished with 0 verified, 1 error
```

Line 4, column 9 is the `/` symbol, indicating division.

Asserting that `d - 1 != 0` does not help.

What does this error mean? How can I convince Dafny this is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the type of `(d - 1)` is `int`.

This fixes it:

```
let d1: nat = d - 1;
q := n / d1;
```

My intent with this code was that all operations should be `nat` arithmetic. Dafny had other ideas. Here is what I think is going on (speculation ahead):

- Dafny has an initial type inference pass that happens *before* the prover runs. This algorithm has no way to make use of assertions and preconditions; it only type-checks them. It does not "know" that `d - 1` is guaranteed to be positive or even that `d > 1`.
- So to Dafny's type-checker, when `d` is a `nat`, `d - 1` has to be an `int`. The result of subtracting a `nat` from a `nat` can be negative.
- Given that, it's not obvious that this program is well-typed. But that's OK! Dafny's type inference can just defer judgment on this point. It allows `n / (d - 1)` to be used as a `nat` here, and it makes a note to have the prover check that the value of `n / (d - 1)` really is guaranteed to fall in the `nat` subset of its type `int`.
- Surprisingly, the prover can't handle this. I checked by changing the return type so that type-checking passes without a hitch:

  ```
  method Div(n: nat, d: nat) returns (q: int)
    requires d > 1
    ensures q >= 0
  {
    q := n / (d - 1);
  }
  ```

  Sure enough, Dafny 2.1.1.10209 fails to prove the postcondition.

Comment: Your four bullets that describe Dafny's behavior are spot on. But in the same way, the type checker treats the result of the `nat` divided-by `nat` as `int`. So, the reason your fix works is because you're introducing a new variable.

Comment: Is that really the case in Dafny? Euclidean division of two natural numbers always produces a natural number. And I couldn't immediately trigger this error using only addition, multiplication, and division—subtraction seems necessary.

Comment: Yes, with Euclidean division, `a / b` and `a % b` each yields a natural number if `a` and `b` are natural numbers (and `b` is non-zero).

Comment: While linear arithmetic is well behaved, it is harder to predict how non-linear arithmetic will fare. My general strategy for working with non-linear arithmetic is to keep breaking down the problem into smaller pieces until it goes through the verifier. In this case, it seemed that introducing a name for the expression `d - 1` was enough, so I stopped there. It is possible that the verifier performs different rewrites for subtraction than for addition. Sorry that I can't give a more precise diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that Dafny in unable to prove that the value assigned to `q` really is a `nat`, as required by `q`'s type. This is strange, because your dividend and divisor are both non-negative. The verifier is generally quite good at linear arithmetic, but your example goes beyond linear arithmetic (since the divisor is not a literal constant) and then the verifier is more flakey.

Playing around with it, my guess is that the subtraction in the denominator gets preprocessed in some way that makes it hard for the verifier to apply what it knows about non-linear division. I was able to find a workaround by giving the term `d - 1` a name, like this:

```
method Div(n: nat, d: nat) returns (q: nat)
  requires d > 1
{
  var y := d - 1;
  q := n / y;
}
```

Rustan